# Set VisualState of combobox when a item is selected in Xaml (Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, xaml, combobox

When my combobox expands and I select an item, I want the combobox to change visual state(it is highlighted). This will signify something is selected. I tried various VisualStates but none of them would trigger in this scenario. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard ComboBox simply doesn't have states to distinguish between having something selected and having nothing selected.

There are a number of ways to go about solving the underlying problem, and it depends mostly on the answer to the following question:

Do you really need to change the visual appearance of the ComboBox itself or does it suffice to style the selected item more prominently?

If it's the latter, you're best served with the rather easy way of using a custom control template for the ComboBoxItems.

If you really want to style the ComboBox itself that way, there are two options I can think of:

**A)** Add custom states to a ComboBox with a custom template.

Copy your ComboBox's control template and add another state group to the already present states. Both of this is typically done in Expression Blend.

After that you can update the new states in code with

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Selected", true);
```

for example. You will have to set those states yourself when the first item is chosen. This could be done on the SelectionChanged event.

**B)** Derive from ComboBox

If you want to use the control in this way often, it might be worthwhile to derive from ComboBox to make your own custom control.

It would look somthing like this:

```
[TemplateVisualState(Name = "SelectedStates", GroupName = "Unselected")]
[TemplateVisualState(Name = "SelectedStates", GroupName = "Selected")]
// ... (more attributes copied from the ComboBox ones)
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public MyComboBox()
    {
        SelectionChanged += HandleSelectionChanged;

        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyComboBox);
    }

    void HandleSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, SelectedItem != null ? "Selected" : "Unselected", true);
    }
}
```

And you would then need a default style based on the default ComboBox style (or whatever you usually use).

Note that I didn't test this in any way.